# Wifi does not work after waking from suspend

Tags: 16.04, wireless

Every time I wake my computer by opening the lid, my WLAN function gets soft blocked. I have to execute `sudo rfkill unblock 0` to re-enable wifi. Is there a fix so that I don't have to unblock every single time?